# how to set bottom line width of the border of the component?

Tags: javascript, extjs4

This way is not working:

```
this.items = [
        {
            height: 35,
            layout: 'hbox',
            border: '0 0 3 0',
            items: [.....
```

Does anybody know how to show only bottom line of the border?

Comment: You need to define the measurement type i.e. 0 0 3px 0.

Comment: it doesn't helped, but i have just figured that like this is ok - border: false,
                style: {
                    borderBottom: '3px solid #99BCE8'
                },

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can set it like this :

```
border: false,
componentCls: 'bottom-border',
```

and css

```
.bottom-border {
border-bottom: 1px solid #99BBE8;
}
```

Comment: oh, sorry.i did'nt see your comment